# RSA encryption large data by blocks

Tags: c#, encryption, .net-core, rsa

For encrypt, decrypt, sign, and verify sign I use code from here [DotnetCore.RSA](https://github.com/stulzq/DotnetCore.RSA)

And it worked well until I started to work with large text.

Encrypt via RSA doesn't work with large text. Large it is more than 245 bytes with 2048 RSA key

I have an exception while trying to encrypt large text:

Exception message: `Interop.Crypto.OpenSslCryptographicException: 'error:0406D06E:rsa routines:RSA_padding_add_PKCS1_type_2:data too large for key size'`

Encrypt function:

```
public string Encrypt(string text) {
  if (_publicKeyRsaProvider == null) {
    throw new Exception("_publicKeyRsaProvider is null");
  }
  return Convert.ToBase64String(_publicKeyRsaProvider.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text), RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1));
}
```

A developer who wrote DotnetCore.RSA suggest to break a long text into many small ones and encrypt them separately and concatenate them

Any suggestions, it's normal or not? Maybe suggestion some libraries for .net Core for RSA encryption

Comment: While splitting in multiple chunks and RSA-encrypt each is possible - it's usually not the way to go, mostly because RSA is very slow (thousands of times slower than symmetric encryption). Way to go is to generate symmetric key (for AES algorithm for example), encrypt the text with symmetric algorithm (AES), then encypt only generated AES key with RSA and prepend to encrypted text. On receiving end - you first extract encrypted AES key (prepended to text), decrypt it with RSA, and then decrypt the text with it.

Comment: @Evk Thanks! very good technology :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A developer who wrote DotnetCore.RSA suggest to break a long text into many small ones and encrypt them separately and concatenate them

That's not the best approach (politely said). Common approach to work with RSA (even for shorter inputs) is using [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

Reasons behind this approach are

- RSA encryption is SLOW. Very slow comparing to symmetric one.
- even for small output the RSA encryption output is way longer
- RSA in certain situations (small message space) may have some weaknesses

Basically you create a random encryption key, encrypt data of any length using any secure symmetric cipher (e.g. AES, 3DES, Salsa, whatever..) and then use RSA to encrypt the symmetric encryption key.